# How to make my Android-Chromecast app visible in the official Chromecast apps Google page?

Tags: android, publish, chromecast, visible

I succesfully integrated my Android app with Chromecast, I have published both and all is working great, in the developer console I enabled the listing app switch and filled all the required fields but my app isn't visible in chromecast.com/apps
Must I do anything more? I published them three days ago

Thank you in advance

Comment: How long has it been since you did this?

Comment: Hi Ali, I published both, Chromecast and Android app update three days ago. And they are working perfectly since they got available to the end-user

Comment: I do remember that it may take up to a week for things to start showing up.

Comment: If "for things" do you refer to the Chromecast app to become visible in the google chromecast apps page it can be, so i will wait. It would be great if google say that in the official documentation. Thank you very much Ali, I really appreciate your help

Comment: Yes, that is what I am referring to, so please wait for about a week and if it didn't show up after a week, please contact us at https://support.google.com/cast-developer/contact/google_cast_contact_us?hl=en&rd=1 so we can further assist you with this issue.

Comment: A few weeks ago our app appeared (a bit hidden) in the web, so it is solved now, thank you Ali